# Geometry matrix colinearity prove

Tags: matrix, geometry

Let's say I have this matrix with n=4 and m=5

```
 1  2  3  4  5
 6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Let's say I have a diagonal from the (1,2) point to the (4,5) point. And I have a point P(3,4). How can I check in my algorithm that P is on the diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Instead of an n-by-m matrix, think about it like a x-y grid.  You can get the equation of a line on that grid, and once you have that equation, you put the `x` coordinate of the point you are interested in checking into your equation.  If the `y` value you calculate from the equation matches the `y` coordinate of the point you are checking, the point lies on the line.

---

**But How Do I Maths?**

First some quick terminology.  We have 3 points of interest in this case - the two points that define the line (or "diagonal", as the OP calls it), and the one point that we want to check.  I'm going to designate the coordinates of the "diagonal" points with the numbers `1` and `2`, and the point we want to check with the letter `i`.  Additionally, for the math we need to do later, I need to treat the horizontal and vertical coordinates of the points separately, and I'll use your n-by-m convention to do so.  So when I write `n1` in an equation below, that is the `n` coordinate of the first point used to define the diagonal (so the `1` part of the point (1,2) that you give in your example).

What we are looking for is the equation of a line on our grid.  This equation will have the form `n = (slope) * m + (intercept)`.

Okay, now that we have the definitions taken care of, we can write the equations.  The first step to solving the problem is finding the slope of your line.  This will be the change in the vertical coordinate divided by the change in the horizontal component between the two points that define the line (so `(n2 - n1) / (m2 - m1)`).  Using the values from your example, this will be `(4 - 1) / (5 - 2) = 3 / 3 = 1`.  Note that since you are doing a division here, it is possible that your answer will not be a whole number, so make sure you keep that in mind when declaring your variables in whatever programming language you end up using - unintentional rounding in this step can really mess things up later.

Once we have our slope, the next step is calculating our intercept.  We can do this by plugging our slope and the `m` and `n` coordinates into the equation for the line we are trying to get.  So we start with the equation `n1 = (slope) * m1 + (intercept)`.  We can rearrange this equation to `(intercept) = n1 - (slope) * m1`.  Plugging in the values from our example, we get `(intercept) = 1 - (1 * 2) = -1`.

So now we have the general equation of our line, which for our example is `n = (1) * m + (-1)`.

Now that we have the `(slope)` and `(intercept)`, we can plug in the coordinates of any point we want to check and see if the numbers match up.  Our example point has a `m` coordinate of `4`, so we can plug that into our equation.

`n = (1) * (4) + (-1) = 3`

**Since the `n` coordinate we calculated using our equation matches the `n` coordinate of our point in our example, we can say that the sample point DOES fall on the line.**

Suppose we wanted to also check to see if the point (2,5) was also on the line.  When we plug that point's `m` coordinate into our equation, we get...

`n = (1) * (5) + (-1) = 4`

Since the `n` coordinate we calculated with our equation (`4`) doesn't match the `n` coordinate of the point we were checking (`2`), **we know this point DOES NOT fall on the line.**

Comment: How to find m and b ?

Comment: Note that these calculations only depend on the coordinates of the grid, and not on the value at that coordinate of the grid (so the values like `16 17 18 19 20` in the example are never used in any of these calculations)